# Ignoring NaN in number field on Validation of InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a Purchase Order form which I need to calculate any entered values automatically (for totals, tax etc). Problem is, some of these fields in the InfoPath form have their default values as a calculation for this purpose. Fine.. but the problem then arises when a line is blank (there are 12 lines in the form but not all may be used in one PO). If a line is blank then the calculated fields will of course, display 'NaN'. For example the Quantity and Price fields are multiplied to make the total, then the total is multiplied by the tax percentage to get the net total. I attach a screenshot below for ease of understanding:
[image: Screenshot of form]

This is fine when it's line 1, as line 1 will definitely be filled in, but not for the others. See line 6 as a demo which is causing this problem. I have tried no default and '0' in the static fields, but neither works unless I put in an integer in (which then confuses users). The form validation insists that a number is in the number fields (not 'NaN'), so is there any way I can either ignore that on form validation, or find another workaround to solve this issue?

For reference, the calculations input as the default value for these are as follows:
Quantity: 0
Price per item: 0
Pre-tax price: Line6Quantity * Line6Price
VAT: (Line6Total - Line6SubTotal) / Line6Total
Line total: Line6SubTotal * (1 + Line6VAT)

As you can see, the VAT/Line Total fields are designed to be interchangeable, so people can fill in either/or. The form is being filled in from SharePoint.

Hope this all makes sense; help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an easy workaround by checking the value in a function called before the form is submitted. So add an onClick="checkForNaN()" function to your submit form.

The isNaN() function should come in handy as you scan through the input boxes to check whether they evaluate to NaN. If so, simply change them to something acceptable to your form validation code.

Comment: Problem then is that the values would still be changed upon submission. When the budget holder then looks at it for approval, they may be confused as to why random fields are completed with meaningful values, yet there is no info on what said item is. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: One way around this would be to use hidden fields for those input boxes where NaN is a possibility, and then populate the hidden fields using that onClick function. A bit inelegant, admittedly, but would avoid the need to re-enter the form fields.

Comment: But there are equally times when they *will* need to be used, in case all lines of the form are used. Ideally I'd like to be able to say if Line5Description is blank, then ignore validation on all other Line5 fields.